# result of Rpart as dummy matrix

Tags: r, rpart

Consider the following run of `rpart`:

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number, data = kyphosis)
```

My question is: how can I transform the content of:

`fit$splits`

into a dummy matrix. E.g. I get:

```
> fit$split
       count ncat  improve index adj
Number    81   -1 2.866795   5.5   0
Age       81   -1 2.250212  39.5   0
```

so the dummy matrix will have one column:

`ifelse(Age > 39.5, 1, 0)`

and likewise for `Number`.

`ifelse(Number > 5.5, 1, 0)`

Comment: This is not quite what you're asking for, but you may find it useful.  You can use this code to give you a single factor that indicates the predicted terminal node ... `rpart:::pred.rpart(fit, rpart:::rpart.matrix(kyphosis))`.  See also: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/rpart-predict-terminal-nodes-for-new-observations-td4630104.html

Comment: @JeanV.Adams: it solves my problem. Thanks!